# Extract <SONGTITLE /> line from ShoutCast V2 xml

Tags: javascript, php, echo

Good,
I have this echo php code that tries to extract from Shoutcast v2 XML the line "SONGTITLE", but I'm not getting it, I get an error and I come to help if you can detect the error that I change more lines I'm not to achieve. I provide the code:

```html
$url = file_get_contents("http://195.201.22.163:8010/stats?sid=1");
$xml = simplexml_load_string($url);
foreach ($xml->SONGTITLE as $cancion)
$cancion = utf8_decode($cancion);

$select = explode(" - ",$cancion);
$artista = chop($select[0]);
$titulo  = chop($select[1]);

echo "$artista";
echo "$titulo";
```

I thank you for your help and availability.

Answer (score 0):

You might be getting undefined offset error. what error is showing at your end?
You can use the below code for fixing the offset error. Also, share more details about what you want to achieve so that I can help you in a better way.

```
$url = file_get_contents("http://195.201.22.163:8010/stats?sid=1");
$xml = simplexml_load_string($url);
foreach ($xml->SONGTITLE as $cancion){
 $cancion = utf8_decode($cancion);
 $titles = explode(" - ",$cancion); 
  foreach ($titles as $title) {
   echo $title;
  }
 }
 //Output : RCM 96
```

Comment: After trying your code I still get the same error "Warning: file_get_contents (http://195.201.22.163:8010/stats?sid=1): failed to open stream:" and still "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach () ". I don't know if it has anything to do with permissions. What I want is inside the XML link to get the SONGTITLE line.

Comment: I think you are passing the URL to file_get_content without HTTP  protocol.
use the Exact URL mentioned in my answer (include HTTP).